# Хлебные крошки работают не полностью - не достаточно глубоко

Tags: php, wordpress

Купил тему для Wordpress, а в ней оказываются не правильно работают breadcrumbs. Даже сами разработчики признают этот косяк. Помогите добиться полного пути в breadcrumbs. Отображается только "Главная > страница на которой находимся", между ними весь путь пропадает. Вот код:

```
public static function breadcrumbs() {



        ob_start();



        if (is_home()) {}

        else {

            echo '<!--breadcrumbs--><nav role="navigation" class="breadcrumbs clearfix">';

            echo '<ul>';

            echo '<li><a href="' . home_url() . '" title="' . __('Home', 'bookyourtravel') . '">' . __('Home', 'bookyourtravel') . '</a></li>';

            if (is_category()) {

                echo "<li>";

                the_category('</li><li>');

                echo "</li>";

            } elseif (is_page() || is_single()) {

                echo "<li>";

                echo the_title();

                echo "</li>";

            } elseif (is_404()) {

                echo "<li>" . __('Error 404 - Page not found', 'bookyourtravel') . "</li>";

            } elseif (is_search()) {

                echo "<li>";

                echo __('Search results for: ', 'bookyourtravel');

                echo '"<em>';

                echo get_search_query();

                echo '</em>"';

                echo "</li>";

            } else if (is_post_type_archive('accommodation')) {

                echo "<li>";

                echo __('Accommodations', 'bookyourtravel');

                echo "</li>";

            } else if (is_post_type_archive('location')) {

                echo "<li>";

                echo __('Locations', 'bookyourtravel');

                echo "</li>";

            }



            echo '</ul>';

            echo '</nav><!--//breadcrumbs-->';

        }



        $breadcrumbs = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();

        echo apply_filters( 'byt_breadcrumbs', $breadcrumbs );

    }
```

Comment: Я совсем не знаю, как работает WP, но попробуйте удалить/поудалять поочередно `else` там, где идет `else if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я пользуюсь - нареканий нет

```
function breadcrumbs() {

/* === ОПЦИИ === */
$text['home'] = 'Головна'; // текст ссылки "Главная"
$text['category'] = '%s'; // текст для страницы рубрики
$text['search'] = 'Результати пошука по запиту "%s"'; // текст для страницы с результатами поиска
$text['tag'] = 'Записи з тегом "%s"'; // текст для страницы тега
$text['author'] = 'Статті автора %s'; // текст для страницы автора
$text['404'] = 'Помилка 404'; // текст для страницы 404
$text['page'] = 'Сторінка %s'; // текст 'Страница N'
$text['cpage'] = 'Сторінка комментаріїв %s'; // текст 'Страница комментариев N'

$wrap_before = '<div class="breadcrumbs">'; // открывающий тег обертки
$wrap_after = '</div><!-- .breadcrumbs -->'; // закрывающий тег обертки
$sep = '›'; // разделитель между "крошками"
$sep_before = '<span class="sep">'; // тег перед разделителем
$sep_after = '</span>'; // тег после разделителя
$show_home_link = 1; // 1 - показывать ссылку "Главная", 0 - не показывать
$show_on_home = 0; // 1 - показывать "хлебные крошки" на главной странице, 0 - не показывать
$show_current = 1; // 1 - показывать название текущей страницы, 0 - не показывать
$before = '<span class="current">'; // тег перед текущей "крошкой"
$after = '</span>'; // тег после текущей "крошки"
/* === КОНЕЦ ОПЦИЙ === */

global $post;
$home_link = home_url('/');
$link_before = '<span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">';
$link_after = '</span>';
$link_attr = ' itemprop="url"';
$link_in_before = '<span itemprop="title">';
$link_in_after = '</span>';
$link = $link_before . '<a href="%1$s"' . $link_attr . '>' . $link_in_before . '%2$s' . $link_in_after . '</a>' . $link_after;
$frontpage_id = get_option('page_on_front');
$parent_id = $post->post_parent;
$sep = ' ' . $sep_before . $sep . $sep_after . ' ';

if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {

    if ($show_on_home) echo $wrap_before . '<a href="' . $home_link . '">' . $text['home'] . '</a>' . $wrap_after;

} else {

    echo $wrap_before;
    if ($show_home_link) echo sprintf($link, $home_link, $text['home']);

    if ( is_category() ) {
        $cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'), false);
        if ($cat->parent != 0) {
            $cats = get_category_parents($cat->parent, TRUE, $sep);
            $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)$sep$#", "$1", $cats);
            $cats = preg_replace('#<a([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/a>#', $link_before . '<a$1' . $link_attr .'>' . $link_in_before . '$2' . $link_in_after .'</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
            if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
            echo $cats;
        }
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            $cat = $cat->cat_ID;
            echo $sep . sprintf($link, get_category_link($cat), get_cat_name($cat)) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['page'], get_query_var('paged')) . $after;
        } else {
            if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . sprintf($text['category'], single_cat_title('', false)) . $after;
        }

    } elseif ( is_search() ) {
        if (have_posts()) {
            if ($show_home_link && $show_current) echo $sep;
            if ($show_current) echo $before . sprintf($text['search'], get_search_query()) . $after;
        } else {
            if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
            echo $before . sprintf($text['search'], get_search_query()) . $after;
        }

    } elseif ( is_day() ) {
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        echo sprintf($link, get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')), get_the_time('Y')) . $sep;
        echo sprintf($link, get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'), get_the_time('m')), get_the_time('F'));
        if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_time('d') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        echo sprintf($link, get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')), get_the_time('Y'));
        if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_time('F') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
        if ($show_home_link && $show_current) echo $sep;
        if ($show_current) echo $before . get_the_time('Y') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) {
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
            $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
            $slug = $post_type->rewrite;
            printf($link, $home_link . '/' . $slug['slug'] . '/', $post_type->labels->singular_name);
            if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
        } else {
            $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
            $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, $sep);
            if (!$show_current || get_query_var('cpage')) $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)$sep$#", "$1", $cats);
            $cats = preg_replace('#<a([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/a>#', $link_before . '<a$1' . $link_attr .'>' . $link_in_before . '$2' . $link_in_after .'</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
            echo $cats;
            if ( get_query_var('cpage') ) {
                echo $sep . sprintf($link, get_permalink(), get_the_title()) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['cpage'], get_query_var('cpage')) . $after;
            } else {
                if ($show_current) echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
            }
        }

        // custom post type
    } elseif ( !is_single() && !is_page() && get_post_type() != 'post' && !is_404() ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            echo $sep . sprintf($link, get_post_type_archive_link($post_type->name), $post_type->label) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['page'], get_query_var('paged')) . $after;
        } else {
            if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . $post_type->label . $after;
        }

    } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        $parent = get_post($parent_id);
        $cat = get_the_category($parent->ID); $cat = $cat[0];
        if ($cat) {
            $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, $sep);
            $cats = preg_replace('#<a([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/a>#', $link_before . '<a$1' . $link_attr .'>' . $link_in_before . '$2' . $link_in_after .'</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
            echo $cats;
        }
        printf($link, get_permalink($parent), $parent->post_title);
        if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && !$parent_id ) {
        if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && $parent_id ) {
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        if ($parent_id != $frontpage_id) {
            $breadcrumbs = array();
            while ($parent_id) {
                $page = get_page($parent_id);
                if ($parent_id != $frontpage_id) {
                    $breadcrumbs[] = sprintf($link, get_permalink($page->ID), get_the_title($page->ID));
                }
                $parent_id = $page->post_parent;
            }
            $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($breadcrumbs); $i++) {
                echo $breadcrumbs[$i];
                if ($i != count($breadcrumbs)-1) echo $sep;
            }
        }
        if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            $tag_id = get_queried_object_id();
            $tag = get_tag($tag_id);
            echo $sep . sprintf($link, get_tag_link($tag_id), $tag->name) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['page'], get_query_var('paged')) . $after;
        } else {
            if ($show_current) echo $sep . $before . sprintf($text['tag'], single_tag_title('', false)) . $after;
        }

    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
        global $author;
        $author = get_userdata($author);
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
            echo sprintf($link, get_author_posts_url($author->ID), $author->display_name) . $sep . $before . sprintf($text['page'], get_query_var('paged')) . $after;
        } else {
            if ($show_home_link && $show_current) echo $sep;
            if ($show_current) echo $before . sprintf($text['author'], $author->display_name) . $after;
        }

    } elseif ( is_404() ) {
        if ($show_home_link && $show_current) echo $sep;
        if ($show_current) echo $before . $text['404'] . $after;

    } elseif ( has_post_format() && !is_singular() ) {
        if ($show_home_link) echo $sep;
        echo get_post_format_string( get_post_format() );
    }

    echo $wrap_after;

}
```

}

Comment: Спасибо, помогли